# Run awscli from AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to execute awscli for s3 sync from AWS Lambda.
When I use ./aws I get following error:

> ('Status : FAIL', 127, 's3: ./aws: No such file or directory\n')

Even tried using full path but still got error:

> ('Status : FAIL', 127, 's3: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/aws: No such file or directory
> ')

Comment: If I recall correctly, everything you can do with the AWS cli can be done via boto3 (Actually, when you look at the source code, you can see that the cli is just an interface to boto3), so is there a reason you want to go through the cli instead of using boto3, since that is what it will ultimately end up using anyways (you can confirm this by viewing the code here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/awscli/clidriver.py)? It will be more efficient than using the cli and probably easier than trying to install the awscli and implement error handling in a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the AWS SDK which is implemented in AWS Lambda. With this you can access S3 and many other AWS services.

Try to look [here](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/resources.html) for programming in Python

The other SDKs can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/de/documentation/).
Remember that you can just use the supported languages for Lambda.

Comment: I am using awscli from Python subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS CLI is not installed on AWS Lambda, so that won't work out of the box.

As the AWS CLI is just a Python package, you could upload it as part of your deployment package if you're using Python as runtime.

Comment: I have installed and also uploaded awscli package but still I get this error.

Comment: Even tried using full path to aws but still same error:('Status : FAIL', 127, 's3: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/aws: No such file or directory
')

Comment: Well, you of course have to use the correct path. The one you're using is obviously not correct.

Comment: Also as mentioned by luccas if you don't have a really good reason to use the awscli, you should use the pre-installed AWS SDK in AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I've used AWS CLI in AWS Lambda - by adding it as a Layer. You can add this as a layer by codifying thee Lambda infrastructure using CDK constructs.

https://pypi.org/project/aws-cdk.lambda-layer-awscli/

In my use case - I wanted to run `aws s3 sync` commmand.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Python boto3 which is already included within your Lambda environment. You can use it to upload to your S3 bucket, as far as I know it doesn't use the sync command but will work the same as the aws s3 cp command used in the CLI.